# Drap/ drop item use CDK in angular grid layout

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I want to build the function drag/drop using CDK show grid layout like
this demo: https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/

But can't do that. I can only do it like this demo https://angular-dragdrop-grid-dj41ya.stackblitz.io and https://angular-6dq2i1.stackblitz.io

NOTE: I don't want to use the gridster library. It just needs to use CDK in angular like what I did in the example above.

Hope everyone can help me. Thank so much

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO :) Please, first read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update your question according to SO guidelines. This will improve your question quality and attract better answers.

Comment: Example you have mentioned as what you want is based on angular gridster2 npm library. It has lot of advanced functionalities than current existing angular drag drop cdk. So you might need to decide whether to use the gridster library or not first.

Comment: If so checkout this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/gridster-in-angular?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I dont want to usse gridster library. I need to use cdk in angular